# Converting Parts of an Array in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm supposed to tag this as homework, but I'm not sure how. Not asking for an answer, just to be pointed in the right direction of what I'm doing wrong. Basically, this is supposed to make a complete sentence out of ANY user input, with the exception of -AllCaps, which is functioning properly. My problem is the other part.

```
param ($title, [switch]$AllCaps)
$ex="to|a|the|at|in|of|with|and|but|or"
function Proper($ts)
{
$nt=foreach($word in $ts)
{
    $word=$word.ToLower()

    if($word -match $ex)
    {
        if($word -eq $ts[0])
        {
            $letters=$word -csplit("")
            $letters[1]=$letters[1].ToUpper()
            $word=$letters -join("")
        }
        else
        {
            $word=$word
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $letters=$word -csplit("")
        $letters[1]=$letters[1].ToUpper()
        $word=$letters -join("")
    }
    "$word"
}
$nt=$nt -join(" ")
Write-host $nt
}

if($AllCaps)
{
$title=$title.ToUpper()
    "$title"
}
else
{
    $ts=$title -split(" ")
    $newtitle=Proper $ts
}
```

So, when I execute the script passing in "the waffle of kings", expected output is "The Waffle of Kings" - instead, the code seems to be completely ignoring the "else" in the first "if else" statement, and the output I'm getting is "The waffle of kings". Since "waffle" doesn't match anything in $ex, it should be moving to the else part, capitalizing the first letter.

Less of note is that it doesn't write to the console without including "$word" within the foreach loop, though the way I have it written, the Write-Host should be doing that for me. If I take out the write-host nothing changes, but if I take out the "$word" in the loop, I get no output at all.

Comment: Also just realized I still have the $newtitle at the very bottom there. That's because I also tried doing a write-host after calling the Proper function, but that didn't work either. Just never took it out.

Comment: `$ex='^(to|a|the|at|in|of|with|and|but|or)$'`

Comment: Also consider this input: `The Waffle of The Kings`.

Comment: PetSerAl has the fix. Currently your regex is looking for matches that are not anchored so it would match waffle since it contains the letter a. Putting in anchors solves this issue.

Comment: I thought I'd respond to your last statement. The reason why you need the "$word" is because that is what is being added to $nt. Without it $nt just becomes a list of nothing. eg: $nt=(foreach ($word in $words) {  }) yeilds nothing. You require some form of variable output in order to populate $nt for Write-Host to do anything.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense in my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the above mentioned

```
$ex='^(to|a|the|at|in|of|with|and|but|or)$'
```

I ended up with a good one-liner, but have expanded it out here:

```
Function Proper($words)
{
  $ex='^(to|a|the|at|in|of|with|and|but|or)$'
  $nt = $(
    foreach ($word in $words)
    {
      $word = $word.ToLower();
      if ($word -match $ex)
      {
        $word
      } else
      {
        $word = ([String]$word[0]).ToUpper()+$word.Substring(1);
        $word
      }
    }
  ) -join " "
  return $nt
}
```

I hope that helps.

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: If you are going to use  PetSerAl's comment you might as well use both of them :)

Comment: Both of them? I replace the ex line as per his solution, but the algorithm in the original post still only capitalised the first letter of the first word. I rewrote it from scratch based on what I guessed the solution needed to be. I assume the other comment was in relation to keeping a capitalised first letter if it was already capitalised? That would depend on what the OP wanted.

Comment: nvm. I re-read the code and the first thing you do with every word is make it lowercase to start.

Comment: I tried using substrings, but switched to the subarray of letters because of this error when saving the script:

"Exception calling "Substring" with "1" arguments: "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex"

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I'm gonna mark yours the answer with the addition of the substring. Much thanks, everyone. Sorry it took me so long to get back to you. I've learned a lot from you guys.